# How to make child Tree Items checked/un-checked if parent Tree was made checked/un-checked

Tags: java, checkbox, tree, swt

I'm having a Check-box Tree View structure, consisting of parent and child nodes.

I want to make all the child nodes [of the parent node] appear as checked if parent Tree is checked. Similarly, if parent Tree is unchecked then its childrens should be unchecked.

Comment: Please check this link: http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet274.java   Basically you need to add selection listener on treeitem so that whenever an item is selected you can check/uncheck its children tree items

Comment: @IshanRastogi: How to retrieve the list of items that has been checked in the Tree view  ?

Comment: Should i manually parse all the Tree Items for checked state but it is a costiler operation. Any method exists for doing this ?

Comment: I am afraid that that is the only way to get all the checked items. Or may be you can keep adding all the checked items in a list separately. Whenever an item is checked you will get a notification in the selection listener based on its state checked/unchecked you can add/remove the item from the list.

Comment: Take a look at the JFace **CheckboxTreeViewer**, You can use the _setSubtreeChecked()_ to check the children and _getCheckedElements()_ to get the checked elements from the tree. Even if you choose not to use it, taking a look at the code could give you some ideas on how it can be done.

Comment: @Monikka That sounds like the best option. Care to create an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to achieve this would be using the JFace **CheckboxTreeViewer** as it has the following predefined methods to simplify the task.

1. `setSubtreeChecked` -  Sets the child elements checked on selecting the parent node
2. `getCheckedElements` - Gets all the checked tree elements

   ```
   final CheckboxTreeViewer treeViewer = new CheckboxTreeViewer(parent);

   // When user checks a checkbox in the tree, check all its children
   treeViewer.addCheckStateListener(new ICheckStateListener() {
   public void checkStateChanged(CheckStateChangedEvent event) {
       // If the item is checked . . .
       if (event.getChecked()) {
         // . . . check all its children
         treeViewer.setSubtreeChecked(event.getElement(), true);
       }
     }
   });

   // Get the selected elements from the tree
   Object[] actuallyChecked = treeViewer.getCheckedElements();
   ```

Comment: If the parent node is unchecked, its children will not be unchecked too. So I modify your code and here is my code `treeViewer.addCheckStateListener(new ICheckStateListener() {
    public void checkStateChanged(CheckStateChangedEvent event) {
 treeViewer.setSubtreeChecked(event.getElement(),event.getChecked());
  }
});` Thank you :)